# ROS cpp callback without message type

Tags: c++, callback, message, ros

I want to create a ROS node that is able to listen to a topic without knowing its message type. In python, this is possible as can be seen here:

https://schulz-m.github.io/2016/07/18/rospy-subscribe-to-any-msg-type/

I tried that and it works like a charm. However, I want to avoid copying the whole message; thus, i need that functionality in a roscpp nodelet.

Comment: This isn't something you can really do in cpp, easily. This is because those template types have to be defined at compile time. What exactly do you mean by "copying the whole message"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that ROS nodelets (if run in the same nodelet manager) can access incoming messages from predecessor nodes by reference. Two nodes however will always get a copy of the message since it is sent via TCP or UDP.
Even if it is hard, I'd like to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By nature, this sort of problem is very pythonic and much harder to work around in c++. That being said, there is one (sort of) solution out there already. Take a look at the [ros_msg_parser](https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_msg_parser).

The syntax isn't pretty, and I'm not even sure if it's a good idea, but it will let you generate generic subscribers. Example from the linked repo:

```
boost::function<void(const RosMsgParser::ShapeShifter::ConstPtr&)> callback;
callback = [&parsers, topic_name](const RosMsgParser::ShapeShifter::ConstPtr& msg) -> void {
    topicCallback(*msg, topic_name, parsers);
};
ros::Subscriber subscriber = nh.subscribe(topic_name, 10, callback);
```

Comment: That works nice and the syntax can be made more readable without boost. Selectively pulling out the header, however, required me to const_cast the raw data of the message. Still, this rather is a discussion for somewhere else. Thanks for your help!